# AudioRecord: how relevant is the bufferSize?

Tags: android, audio, buffer, audiorecord

I am recording audio from the MIC using `AudioRecord`. In its construction, the last parameter is the `bufferSizeInBytes`. This buffer has to be bigger than the value obtained from

```
 int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SampleRate, Channels, AudioEncoding);
```

In my device, this is a strange number: 3528.

How important is the value of `bufferSizeInBytes` to get the smoothest result? I have seen code setting `bufferSizeInBytes = minBufferSize`, while others set
`bufferSizeInBytes = 2*minBufferSize`. How relevant is this?